# Android emulator CTRL+S screenshot location

Tags: android, android-emulator

I used this feature before, to make screenshots using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> and it just saved all of them to my desktop. Now however I do not find any of the screenshots. All I saw online was "how to take a screenshot" which is fine, but I made quite a few in a relatively long time and I don't want to redo it.

So, where does <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> save myscreenshots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a search through device files I finally found it.

`/data/local/tmp/screen.png`

Comment: Thanks, in my searches I looked for the typical image save filenames, that is the current date unformatted.

Comment: It's purely by luck though, there's no way to tell if the future Android Emulator version won't change this :|

Comment: Sod it, in the meantime I had to reinstall the os, and I put back android studio, and it saves to the desktop as it should :D

Answer (score 16):

**macOS 10, Android Studio 3.1.1**

I found it in `/Users/<username>/Desktop/Screenshot_1543994371.png` file.

See `More` button in Android emulator menu for `Settings\General\Screenshot save location` path.

Comment: Windows version of Android Emulator - also has path under `...` (More) icon button, same location as described in this answer.

Answer (score 5):

In Windows 10, Android Studio 3.4, I found it under the emulators directory.

```
C:\Users\<username>\.android\avd\<emulator_name>.avd\snapshots\default_boot
```

Answer (score 5):

On Windows 10, Visual Studio, it ends up on the user's Desktop by default.